# Why get one more lines displayed for the callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1+p").hide();
  $("h1").hover(function() {
      $("+p", this).show(6000, function() {
        $(this).append("<p>animation is completed</p>");
      });
    },
    function() {
      $("+p", this).hide(6000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>introduction</h1>
<p id="pp">it is a test</p>
```

It is a simple animation effect ,`it is a test` will display in 6 seconds when mouse entered into `h1` tag,and `animation is completed` will display  as a callback function's result.
Sometimes i run it on my chrome,`animation is completed` displayed in two lines or more,why?
During the process i do not move the  mouse after move it on the `h1` tag.
[image]

Comment: `+p` includes the `<p>` that you're `append`ing. And since you aren't `.stop()`ping the animation before queuing another one, hovering the mouse on and off of the `<h1>` will cause it to happen multiple times. Try `~p` instead, or even `$(this).next("p")`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You probably shouldnt post the answer as a comment, it bypasses answer voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are appending a new "`animation is completed`" string every time you hover:

`$(this).append("<p>animation is completed</p>");`

And all you do is hide the string afterwards, not remove it:

`$("+p", this).hide(1000);`

Thus for every time you hover over the `h1` element, you will be getting that string + 1.

---

You can use the following to fix the issue:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("h1+p").hide();

        $("h1").hover(function() {
            $("+p", this).show(1000, function() {
                $(this).append("<p class='notice'>animation is completed</p>"); // "notice" class
            });
        },
        function() {
            $("+p", this).hide(1000, function() {
                $(".notice").remove(); // remove "notice" class element
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are simply appending `<p>animation is completed</p>`. That means that every time that you hover your cursor over the element, it will add another 'animation is completed'. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1+p").hide();
  $("h1").hover(function() {
      $("+p", this).show(6000, function() {
        $(this).append("<p>animation is completed</p>");
      });
    },
    function() {
      $("+p", this).hide(6000);
      $("p").not("#pp").remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>introduction</h1>
<p id="pp">it is a test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this line `$(this).append("<p id='anim'>animation is completed</p>");` will keep on appending a new `p` inside the dom with id `pp`. You can remove any child element by using `remove` method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1+p").hide();
  $("h1").hover(function() {
      $("+p", this).show(3000, function() {
        $(this).append("<p id='anim'>animation is completed</p>");
      });
    },
    function() {
      $("+p", this).hide(3000);
      $("#pp").find("#anim").remove()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>introduction</h1>
<p id="pp">it is a test</p>
```